# Make 'background-image' responsive with layout attributes?

Tags: css, polymer, flexbox

Using `Polymer 1.0`, I am trying to do a layout and make the CSS `background-image` be width 100% and height auto. Not sure how to go about this in a `flex-box` or `polymer` layout sort of way. I could use `width: 100%;` but I still have an issue with making the height responsive...the height will only show if I do `height: 500px;`. How do I make the background image show up and be responsive? It has to be a `background-image` attribute.

http://jsbin.com/dojupayiwi/1/edit?html,css,output

```
#video-photo-container {
   background-image: url(http://www.waynestiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/King-David-statue-on-Mount-.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: 100% auto;`

This will match the background to the width of the container and then adjust the height so that it retains the original aspect ratio of the image. There is no way of getting around setting the width/height of the container as far as I know.

Comment: You would still need to set `width: 100%;` and the height to something as well. I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. On a site where I think I did something similar to what you want I have a large background which takes up 100% width and I set the height using a pixel value.